# How to locate a tag name inside a div using xpath and Robotframework

Tags: python, xpath, robotframework

So I am asserting that a particular tag exists in the dom. There is no id or class inside the div so I am using xpath to locate it. I am not sure how to write out the path correctly. The DOM simplified looks as follows

```
<div id="top-list">
<div data-version="12345" data-list="1"  data-point="10">
```

I want to assert that `data-list` exists but the xpath it suggests for me to find that tag is `//*[@id="top-list"]/div[1]`

What do I need to add to that to ensure its looking for `data-list` and not just the div. There are loads of other tags inside that div that I want to assert separately. I am just showing one or two to keep things easy to read.

I tried an xpath like `//*[@id="top-list"]/div[1]["data-list"]` and a few other variations of that, but I can't seem to find the correct path.

Thanks in advance for all help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to *locate node with specific attribute* this one should do the trick:

```
//div[@id="top-list"]/div[@data-list]
```

You can also specify `@data-list` value in XPath:

```
//div[@id="top-list"]/div[@data-list="1"]
```

Comment: Yes that worked a charm. Many thanks. If there were 2 divs say, would it be `//div[@id="top-list"]/div/div[@data-list]`

Comment: @JackGruber if target `div` might be nested in another `div` you can try `//div[@id="top-list"]//div[@data-list]`

Comment: One last quick question if you know off hand. I need to also get the element attribute(value) of that element and set it to a variable. So I am writing `${data-list-element}`  get element attribute  `xpath=//*[@id="top-list"]/div[@data-list]`. That variable is declared on a different file. It can't seem to find the attribute for me when its in a separate file. If I write the variable on the same page as the assertion it works. I am asserting it not equal to empty by using should be not equal  `${data-list-element}  ${empty}` If  variable is set on the same file location it works fine.

Comment: @JackGruber , Unfortunately , I'm not familiar with RobotFramework, so I don't know how to extract attribute value. It'd be better to create separate question for this issue